# Galvanic cell of copper and zinc

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, oxidation-state

When we dip zinc metal in zinc sulfate solution, does zinc sulfate ionize into Zn and sulfate ions? Zinc ions come into the solution as Zn$^{+2}$ so why is the metal not completely dissociated?

Why is zinc sulfate used as an electrolytic solution?

Comment: Basically, this is because we want to know the concentration on $\ce{Zn^2+}$ to plug it into the [Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation). The galvanic cell would work just as well with pretty much any other electrolyte.